# Roslyn - save edited document to physical solution

Tags: roslyn

I'm trying to iterate through all documents, change some code and then rewrite analyzed document with new Syntax. The only problem I have it's that i don't know how to save changed document via workspace. After my code execution nothing happens.

```
var manager = new AnalyzerManager(slnPath);
        foreach (var project in manager.Projects.Values)
        {
            var workspace = project.GetWorkspace();
            var sln = workspace.CurrentSolution;

            foreach (var msBuildProject in sln.Projects)
            {
                foreach (var document in msBuildProject.Documents)
                {
                    var tree = await document.GetSyntaxTreeAsync();
                    var root = tree.GetRoot();
                    var compilation = await msBuildProject.GetCompilationAsync();
                    var walker = new CustomRewriter(compilation, tree);
                    var newRoot = walker.Visit(root);
                    if (!walker.Edited)
                        continue;
                    var editor = await DocumentEditor.CreateAsync(document);
                    editor.ReplaceNode(root, newRoot);
                    var newDocument = editor.GetChangedDocument();
                    workspace.TryApplyChanges(newDocument.Project.Solution);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT: Workspace is fetched with help of the [Buildalyzer](https://github.com/daveaglick/Buildalyzer) package.

Comment: How are you getting the workspace? That is responsible for persisting the data to a file. Without knowing how you created the workspace it will be hard to tell what went wrong

Comment: also `TryApplyChanges` returns `true` if the changes were successfully applied. What does it return in your case?

Comment: I'm usiong Buildalyzer to get the workspace. In my case TryApplyChanges returns true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Buildalyzer` uses the adhoc workspace which does not persist changes. You want to use the MSBuildWorkspace.

You should have a project file that looks something like this

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator" Version="1.2.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="2.9.8" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="3.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces" Version="3.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild" Version="3.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And then this is how I would load your solution and run your rewriter

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Build.Locator;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editing;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;

class Program {
    static async Task Main(string[] args) {
        // Attempt to set the version of MSBuild.
        var visualStudioInstances = MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances().ToArray();
        var instance = visualStudioInstances.Length == 1
            // If there is only one instance of MSBuild on this machine, set that as the one to use.
            ? visualStudioInstances[0]
            // Handle selecting the version of MSBuild you want to use.
            : SelectVisualStudioInstance(visualStudioInstances);

        Console.WriteLine($"Using MSBuild at '{instance.MSBuildPath}' to load projects.");

        // NOTE: Be sure to register an instance with the MSBuildLocator 
        //       before calling MSBuildWorkspace.Create()
        //       otherwise, MSBuildWorkspace won't MEF compose.
        MSBuildLocator.RegisterInstance(instance);

        using (var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create()) {
            // Print message for WorkspaceFailed event to help diagnosing project load failures.
            workspace.WorkspaceFailed += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Diagnostic.Message);

            var solutionPath = args[0];
            Console.WriteLine($"Loading solution '{solutionPath}'");

            // Attach progress reporter so we print projects as they are loaded.
            var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath, new ConsoleProgressReporter());
            Console.WriteLine($"Finished loading solution '{solutionPath}'");

            // Run your custome re-writer on the loaded solution
            foreach (var msBuildProject in solution.Projects) {
                foreach (var document in msBuildProject.Documents) {
                    var tree = await document.GetSyntaxTreeAsync();
                    var root = tree.GetRoot();
                    var compilation = await msBuildProject.GetCompilationAsync();
                    var walker = new CustomRewriter(compilation, tree);
                    var newRoot = walker.Visit(root);
                    if (!walker.Edited)
                        continue;
                    var editor = await DocumentEditor.CreateAsync(document);
                    editor.ReplaceNode(root, newRoot);
                    var newDocument = editor.GetChangedDocument();
                    workspace.TryApplyChanges(newDocument.Project.Solution);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static VisualStudioInstance SelectVisualStudioInstance(VisualStudioInstance[] visualStudioInstances) {
        Console.WriteLine("Multiple installs of MSBuild detected please select one:");
        for (int i = 0; i < visualStudioInstances.Length; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Instance {i + 1}");
            Console.WriteLine($"    Name: {visualStudioInstances[i].Name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"    Version: {visualStudioInstances[i].Version}");
            Console.WriteLine($"    MSBuild Path: {visualStudioInstances[i].MSBuildPath}");
        }

        while (true) {
            var userResponse = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(userResponse, out int instanceNumber) &&
                instanceNumber > 0 &&
                instanceNumber <= visualStudioInstances.Length) {
                return visualStudioInstances[instanceNumber - 1];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Input not accepted, try again.");
        }
    }

    private class ConsoleProgressReporter : IProgress<ProjectLoadProgress> {
        public void Report(ProjectLoadProgress loadProgress) {
            var projectDisplay = Path.GetFileName(loadProgress.FilePath);
            if (loadProgress.TargetFramework != null) {
                projectDisplay += $" ({loadProgress.TargetFramework})";
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"{loadProgress.Operation,-15} {loadProgress.ElapsedTime,-15:m\\:ss\\.fffffff} {projectDisplay}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out type of the workspace used by Buildalyzer. Unfortunately I'm forced to use net core and MSBuildWorkspace doesn't support it at this moment. I think i will end up with saving new tree manually to physical file.

Comment: We use the MSBuildWorkspace on [dotnet-format](https://github.com/dotnet/format) for .NET Core and it works just fine. What specifically didn't work on .NET Core?

Comment: see the loader logic here: https://github.com/dotnet/format/blob/master/src/Program.cs#L107

Comment: I had problem with loading documents. Each project compliation ends up with error that tool is unable to locate MSBuildSDKsPath

Comment: If you use the msbuild that comes with the .NET SDK (and have the .NET SDK installed) it should work. Can you post the actual error you get?

Comment: Sorry for late response. I sit down again to this topic and implemented it from scratch (copy paste your code). I didn't use MSBuildLocator and didn't know that exist! That really help me out, thank you. I wish roslyn documentation was not outdated it seems like important part of the code refactoring for net core

Comment: What documentation did you look at that was outdated?

Comment: I did research (maybe not succesful and i missed something) but from my perspective fetching information is difficult. API browser for MsBuildWorkspace returns nothing, only for Workspace class where there was only one(!) sentence describing functionality (for example msdn describes SyntaxTrivia as 'Trivia in the syntax tree', for a newbie like me it tells nothing). I couldn't find MsBuildWorkspace in github docs either. And googling 'MsBuildWorkspace roslyn' returns issues on github and 404 from external sites